# Scanning for BLE devices in a foreground service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app that can detect and exchange information with BLE devices similar to iBeacons. These devices send an advertisement every 1000ms.

Currently, I have a foreground service that runs some logic, which includes scanning for BLE devices periodically (e.g. once every ten seconds, I run the scanner for 2 seconds). Once I push the app to the background, however, the BLE Scanner changes behaviour, scanning very infrequently. From what I can understand, this is because the OS forces the scanner to use the low power scan mode.

The problem lies in the fact that the scan window is shorter than the BLE Device advertising intervals, so I tend to miss packets. Is there a way to ensure the scanning is able to run for at least this interval, perhaps via scan mode (low latency or balanced) or some other trick?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 running Android 7.0.

---

Edit: Added some sample code (Note: I am using Nativescript, so what you see here is a conversion of the Nativescript code to Java, to the best of my understanding.)

I start the service with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.my.service.MyService);
startService(intent);
```

Service class functions

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentInfo("My App")
        .build()

    this.startForeground(12312, notif);
    runMyScanner();
    this.super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy(){
    this.stopForeground(0); // Corresponds to a flag.
}
```

Scanner

```
private int mNumScanned = 0;

public void runMyScanner(){
    List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    scanFilters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().build())

    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build()

    ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(){
            mNumScanned++;
        }
    }

    mAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(scanFilterList, scanSettings, scanCallback);
}
```

(Note: After scanning, I print out mNumScanned, which has allowed me to investigate the issue. In addition, I stop the scan some number of seconds after starting, but use the javascript method `setTimeout()` to do so)

Comment: Are you sure you are using a foreground service? That usually means that a notification is open, informing the user about the process but it isn't in the "foreground" as app has an open activity. I think that kind of foreground service should work for what you want to do.

Comment: I'm pretty certain. The notification you mention is present (even when the app is closed/destroyed) but the problem persists.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure that worked until Android 7, I never had problems even with extended 30sec scanning intervals. Are you using 8, they did change some background related stuff so that could be. I didn't find time to migrate to 8 yet, maybe try `ScanFilter` that should allow for scanning while screen is off, even on v8.

Comment: This is the Oreo change: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/438218f014a184ee17098175e39ef765a6608211%5E%21/. Basically scanning apps that are neither in the foreground nor has a foreground service should be "downgraded" to low power scan (10% duty).

Comment: @meow I'm running android 7.0 on a Galaxy Tab S2 currently, so the 8.0 problem shouldn't be relevant. I did try adding a blank ScanFilter, but the problem persists. I'm not running the Service in a new thread... could this cause the behavior?

Comment: One thing you could do is to look at the HCI snoop log and see if the phone changes the scan parameters when you "push the app to the background".

Comment: Can you post some code of the service that is supposed to do initialize the scanning?

Comment: @Emil I will try to investigate using that method.

Comment: @meow See edit, I've put in what code I think is relevant to the problem. Let me know if you want me to expand or anything.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond That actually looks ok, really strange. I do wonder why it worked for me. Few things I could think are: scan only every 30 seconds but for 5-10 seconds maybe, stop the service after each scan and start it again with a JobScheduler or AlarmManager, I think you can even set an interval there, move the scanner to another thread (I don't think it matters but I did it for other reasons). And I guess you already did but check your Manifest for the two Bluetooth premissions and if it is not  a third party app maybe even for the `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED`.

Comment: Did you get any fix for that issue? I am having the same error...

Comment: @JoséCarlos I ended up moving to a different platform. Best of luck!

Comment: @ThomasRichmond Me too, but I saw this error and I checked if you got any fix. Thanks ;-)